# Trying to find the index of an entry in a list

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am trying to find the index of an list entry using this simple method:

```
#!/bin/sh

partList="500 1000 2000 4000"
a=( $partList )
echo ${a["500"]}
```

this returns `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. And the same error if I try `echo ${a[500]}`. Where I was hoping it would return `0` if using `500`.

I am simply looking for a quick and dirty way to tell, when am looping over a list as so:

```
 for j in $partList; do
   if [ $j is the first entry in the list $partList ]; then
     stuff happens..
   done
 done
```

whether or not I have used the first element of that list and if so then do some logic.

I thought I could do this easily using the index of the list. But this appears difficult with `#!/bin/sh`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean index of substring in string or index of element in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reversed the lookup process -- array[index] returns something. array[array_element] won't give you the index - you'd need a lookup table (even better, a hash map) for that.

But for what you're doing, you are actually just looping over indices! Instead of `j in $partList` just loop over `j in $(seq ${#partlist[@]})` and use the index to get the element.

Lastly... not even that is needed, if you are really just using the first element, why not just

```
j=${partList[0]}
stuff happens..
```